# Dependency Injector not wiring containers in Flask application

Tags: python, flask, dependency-injection

I'm using Dependency injector on my Flask Project.
When trying to add an expense to my FakeExpenseRepository, i receive the following error:
`AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'get_expense'`

Below is my project structure:

```
\+---src
    +---adapters
    |   +---__init__.py
    |   +---fake_expenses_repository.py
    +---di
    |   +---__init__.py
    |   +---config.py
    |   +---wiring_config.py
    +---ports
    |   +---__init__.py
    |   +---abstract_expenses_repository.py
    +---services
    |   +---__init__.py
    |   +---get_expense.py
    \---web_app
        +---blueprints
        |   +---__init__.py
        |   +---get_expense.py
        +---__init__.py
        +---app.py
```

In config.py

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from adapters.fake_expense_repository import FakeExpenseRepository
from di.wiring_config import wiring_config

class Application(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    wiring_config = wiring_config
    repository = providers.Singleton(FakeExpenseRepository)
```

In wiring_config.py
from dependency_injector import containers

```
wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(modules=["services.get_expense"])
```

In services/get_expense.py

```
from dependency_injector.wiring import Provide, inject

from ports.abstract_expenses_repository import AbstractExpenseRepository

@inject
def execute(id: str, repository: AbstractExpenseRepository = Provide\["repository"\]):
    return repository.get_expense(id)
```

In blueprints/get_expense.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
from services import get_expense

bp = Blueprint("get_expense", __name__)

@bp.route("/expense", methods=\["GET", "POST"\])
def get_expense():
    expense = get_expense.execute(request.json\["expense_id"\])
    if expense:
        return jsonify({"expense": expense})
    return jsonify({"error": "Expense not found"})
```

Finally in app.py

```
from web_app.blueprints import get_expense

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(get_expense.bp)
```

Has anyone encounter the same situation? I would really appreciate some guidance here.
Thanks!